# Combine/Merge time interval rows in a sorted pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, timedelta

I have a sorted pandas dataframe which looks like the following one:

```
SessionNumber     Timestamp_start       Timestamp_complete   Activity   ColB  ColC
2                 2018-02-11 14:17:00   2018-02-11 14:21:00  "A"           3     4
2                 2018-02-11 14:21:00   2018-02-11 14:22:30  "A"           3     4
2                 2018-02-11 14:23:00   2018-02-11 14:28:30  "A"           3     4
2                 2018-02-11 14:29:00   2018-02-11 14:31:30  "B"           3     4
2                 2018-02-11 14:33:00   2018-02-11 14:35:30  "A"           3     4
...        
3                 2018-02-12 08:44:00   2018-02-12 08:50:30  "A"           2     1
3                 2018-02-12 08:51:00   2018-02-12 08:51:30  "A"           2     1
```

I want to combine same activities which followed after each other to one new row depending on the SessionNumber.
The result from this example should be:

```
SessionNumber     Timestamp_start       Timestamp_complete   Activity   ColB  ColC
2                 2018-02-11 14:17:00   2018-02-11 14:28:30  "A"           3     4
2                 2018-02-11 14:29:00   2018-02-11 14:31:30  "B"           3     4
2                 2018-02-11 14:33:00   2018-02-11 14:35:30  "A"           3     4
...        
3                 2018-02-12 08:44:00   2018-02-12 08:51:00  "A"           2     1
```

The dataframe is sorted by the following order: SessionNumber, Timestamp_start, Activity

Inside the same SessionNumber I want to combine entries which are following (by the timestamp) directly after each other. I only want to combine rows when they have the same values in Activity, ColB and ColC and when the time difference between the complete and start timestamp is under a certain threshold (e.g. 30 seconds).
As the dataframe is already sorted, the most obvious idea is to iterate over the rows and combine every 2 rows which match the conditions. For example by dropping one row and set the new Timestamp_complete to the remaining one.

But iterating is a bad idea in pandas...

Is there another idea of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated per comment and question change:

Try this:

```
Activitygrp = (df['Activity'] != df['Activity'].shift().bfill()).cumsum().rename('ActivityGroup')
df_m = (df.groupby(['SessionNumber', 'Activity', Activitygrp, 'ColB', 'ColC'])[['Timestamp_start', 'Timestamp_complete']]
          .agg(Time_start=('Timestamp_start', 'first'),
               Time_end=('Timestamp_complete', 'last')))
df_m.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
|    |   SessionNumber | Activity   |   ActivityGroup |   ColB |   ColC | Time_start          | Time_end            |
|---:|----------------:|:-----------|----------------:|-------:|-------:|:--------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 |               2 | "A"        |               0 |      3 |      4 | 2018-02-11 14:17:00 | 2018-02-11 14:28:30 |
|  1 |               2 | "A"        |               2 |      3 |      4 | 2018-02-11 14:33:00 | 2018-02-11 14:35:30 |
|  2 |               2 | "B"        |               1 |      3 |      4 | 2018-02-11 14:29:00 | 2018-02-11 14:31:30 |
|  3 |               3 | "A"        |               2 |      2 |      1 | 2018-02-12 08:44:00 | 2018-02-12 08:51:30 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I described it in a bad way and missed something. In your solution all same activities are joint together which was perfectly fitting to my example. But I want to merge all same activities that are sequential (by timestamp_start). To emphasize this, I edited my example: Activity "B" is now chronologically between two "A" activities, whereby the last "A" activity should't merge with the first ones.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exact what I needed!